# Defining Eloquent relationships and tables between three Laravel models

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent, model, relationship

I'm working on an admin tool app using Laravel/Vue/Inertia for a club that I belong to, and I'm trying to determine how best to create the Eloquent relationships for three models.

Every year, each member is required to put in a certain number of work hours around the club helping out. The club is broken out into multiple areas, referred to as Disciplines. When a member puts in their time, currently they fill out a paper slip that contains the discipline, the date, the hours, and requires an approval signature by the "owner" of a discipline or a designated approver for the area. This is what I want to implement in my app. When a WorkHours entry is created, the user will enter the date, number of hours, discipline, and a designated approver for that discipline.

What this means is that a user record can be both a) an approver on a Discipline and b) a user for whom the WorkHours record is being submitted (but not both on one WorkHours record, for obviuos reasons).

So as I see it, I need three models and the following fields based on the facts that:

- A Discipline model can have multiple approvers (users) and a user can be an approver for multiple disciplines (aka many to many)
- A WorkHours entry belongs to exactly one user (user_id) and has exactly one approver (approver_id)
- A User can have multiple WorkHours records and belong to multiple Disciplines

**Discipline**

- name
- `approvers() = ->belongsToMany(User::class)`

**WorkHours**

- date
- hours
- `member() = ->belongsTo(User::class)` as `user_id`
- `discipline() = ->belongsTo(Discipline::class)`
- `approver() = ->hasOne(User::class)` as `approver_id`

**User**

- `disciplines() = ->belongsToMany(Discipline::class)`
- `workHours() = ->hasMany(WorkHours::class)`

And my tables and relevant fields would look like this:

**work_hours**

- id
- user_id
- approver_id

**disciplines**

- id
- name

**users**

- id
- name

**disciplines_users**

- user_id
- discipline_id

Does that all seem correct? Or is there a better way I could define my relationships?

Comment: This is a question for [code review](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/)

Comment: Cool, thanks. I was not aware of that site.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As detailed [here](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/283358/three-way-eloquent-relationship-definition-and-saving-in-laravel/283398#283398), this was the answer.

My issue (as I suspected) was in a relationship definition. Once I changed the `approval()` definition in `User` from this

```
    public function approval()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo(WorkHours::class, 'approver_id');
    }
```

to this

```
    public function approvals()
    {
        return $this->haMany(WorkHours::class, 'approver_id');
    }
```

it worked fine. There was no user id value to write since the relationship for the `approver` was wrong, which was why it was looking for a default value.